# Passing variable names into fre command

Tags: r, shiny, expss

I'm trying to pass set of variables into select input, and use its names to `expss::fre` command.

I have object with column names and its labels like *'myvars'*:

```
a1_1, "Do you like apples?"
a1_2, "Do you like oranges?"
```

I'm using them:

```
selectInput(vars, "Select variable", myvars)
```

Then, in 'server' section i would like to use it for generating simple frequency table.

```
output$view <- renderTable( {
        fre(input$variable)
}
```

The problem is that in `fre` I have to pass variable with dataset name:

```
fre(data$a1_1)
```

So I tried with `eval`, `quo`, `!!`, `paste0("data$",input$vars)` and more, but didn't  succeed.

when I try with `switch`:

```
switch(input$vars, "a1_1"=fre(data$a1_1), "a1_2"=fre(data$a1_2))
```

It works fine, but I need more flexible solution. 
How to do this well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should do the trick:

```
output$view <- renderTable({
        fre(data[[input$vars]])
})
```